# Como impedir que AlertDialog seja fechado ao algum botão ser clicado?

Tags: android

**Problema**

Estou tentando validar determinados dados contidos em uma `View` customizada de um `AlertDialog` no evento de clique no botão Salvar. Então após a validação eu salvo os dados e fecho o AlertDialog, e em caso dos dados não serem válidos eu mostraria os erros para serem corrigidos. Mas mesmo que eu não chame o método `dialog.dismiss();` o `AlertDialog` em questão é fechado.

**Pergunta**

> Como eu poderia interceptar e impedir o fechamento automático do `AlertDialog` ao clicar em qualquer de seus botões?

**Tentativa de implementação**

O que estou implementando que não está a funcionar é o seguinte:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
dialog.setTitle("Preencha o formulário:");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_forms, null);
dialog.setView(view);
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.btn_save), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(validForm()){
            save();
            dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            exibirErrosFormulario();
            // ... como não chamo "dialog.dismiss();" não era para fechar o AlertDialog, mas está fechando.
        }
    }
});
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.btn_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Uma outra alternativa é esta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85735/5801.

Comment: @GeisonSantos, que no final é mesma coisa, só dando algumas voltas a mais, pois o segredo da solução é sobrescrever o evento de click dos botões padrões do `Dialog`, como o [@ramaral, indica em sua resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63039/2998).

Comment: A diferença é que eu escrevo menos, @Fernando. No final o resultado é mesmo, sim. É mais uma questão de gosto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu uso um artificio que encontrei já não me lembro onde.

Comece por definir uma classe que irá tratar o *evento* `onClick` do botão do dialog:

```
public abstract class DialogButtonClickWrapper implements OnClickListener{

    private AlertDialog dialog;

    public DialogButtonClickWrapper(AlertDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(onClicked()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean onClicked();
}
```

Declare o botão da forma habitual, mas não introduza nenhum código no `onClick()`:

```
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.btn_save), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
```

Na linha onde tem `dialog.show()` introduza o seguinte código:

```
//É necessário porque os botões só são atribuídos após o método `show` ser chamado
dialog.show();

Button theButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
theButton.setOnClickListener(new DialogButtonClickWrapper(dialog) {

    @Override
    protected boolean onClicked() {

        if(validForm()){
            save();
            return true;//Retornando true fecha o dialog
        } else {
            exibirErrosFormulario();
            return false;//Retornando false o dialog não é fechado
        }
    }
});
```

A classe `DialogButtonClickWrapper` tem apenas o mínimo necessário para esta situação.
A partir dela você pode melhorá-la para, por exemplo, ser ela a validar o formulário e só então chamar o método `onClicked`.

Nesse caso a classe teria um método `private boolean isValid()` que retornará `true` ou `false` consoante a validade dos dados do formulário.
O método `onClick` seria assim:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(isValid()){
        if(onClicked()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

A implementação do método `onClicked` terá o código correspondente à ação do botão, deverá retornar `true` se tudo correr bem ou `false` se algo de errado acontecer.

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui e funciona perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda, estava indignado que isso não era possível. Hehe Obs: editei seu post corrigindo alguns erros na sintaxe, que verifiquei ao implementar aqui. Confira se não fiz nada de errado. =D

Comment: Outra alternativa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85735/5801.