# Como evitar fechamento automático em DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android

Desenvolvi uma tela de login, conforme pode ser visto na figura abaixo, seguindo a seção "**Creating a Custom Layout**" da [documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O único problema que estou enfrentado é que o *dialog* fecha independente da opção em que eu clique. Como evitar que ocorra o fechamento automático quando eu clicar no botão <kbd>ACESSAR</kbd>?

#### Chamada do dialog:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // ...

    public void abrirDialogLogin() {
        DialogFragment dialogLogin = new LoginDialog();
        dialogLogin.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login");
    }
}
```

#### Construção do dialog:

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder
            .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.acessar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //TODO bloquear fechamento automático AQUI
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //TODO pode fechar automaticamente AQUI
                }
            });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63039/2541) ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema relatado precisei realizar pequenos ajustes na classe LoginDialog. A mudança principal ocorreu no método `onCreateDialog()` que agora  retorna o seu valor a partir de `super.onCreateDialog()`.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}
```

Outra importante mudança foi a implementação do método `onCreateView()`. Neste eu faço o binding dos meus botões e retorno uma view contendo o meu layout.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

    Button botaoCancelar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botao_cancelar);
    Button botaoLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botao_login);

    botaoCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO realizando o cancelamento do dialog
        }
    });

    botaoLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO realizar o login
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Até aqui tudo funciona direitinho. Só que o layout aparece com dimensões reduzidas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para contornar o problema o seguinte código deve ser escrito no método `onStart()`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }        
}
```

Prontinho! Tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Código completo da classe LoginDialog

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }        
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

        Button botaoCancelar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botao_cancelar);
        Button botaoLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botao_login);

        botaoCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO realizando o cancelamento do dialog
            }
        });

        botaoLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO realizar o login
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

#### Layout do login

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/fazer_login"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/email"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/senha"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/senha"/>

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/cancelar"
            android:id="@+id/botao_cancelar"/>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/acessar"
            android:id="@+id/botao_login"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

No layout dá para notar a altura e a largura declaradas com o valor máximo (`match_parent`), contudo esses valores são desprezados e necessitam ser sobrescritos durante o ciclo de vida de `DialogFragment`, como pode ser visto no método `onStart()` da classe `LoginDialog`.

Answer (score 3):

Coloque o seguinte código no método `onCreateView()` do seu `DialogFragment`

```
getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```