# Validar EditText dentro do AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Tenho um `AlertDialog` e dentro dele tenho um `EditText` e preciso validar e depois que validar executar o método `enviarEmail()`, como faço?

Meu `AlertDialog` :

```
AlertDialog.Builder caixaDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            caixaDialog.setView(vView)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Enviar", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            // Habilitar todos os botões
                            btnSatisfacaoRuim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_satisfacao_ruim);
                            btnSatisfacaoBom.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_satisfacao_bom);
                            btnSatisfacaoNormal.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_satisfacao_normal);
                            llSatisfacao.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                    });

            final AlertDialog mDialog = caixaDialog.create();
            mDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Button positive = mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (edtMensagemSatEmail.getText().length() == 0) {
                                edtMensagemSatEmail.setError("Campo obrigatório");
                                edtMensagemSatEmail.setFocusable(true);
                                edtMensagemSatEmail.requestFocus();
                            } else {
                                // Barra de progresso
                                progresso = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                                progresso.setCancelable(false);
                                progresso.setMessage("Processando...");
                                progresso.show();

                                // Metodo de envio
                                inserirWEBService();
                                enviarEmail();
                                mDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_principal, new avalieViagem()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            mDialog.show();
```

Meu XML do `Dialog`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Linha: "
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_linha_sat_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="linha"
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Horário: "
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_horario_sat_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="horario"
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_linha_sat_email" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_sat_email"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_satisfacao_bom_off"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="69dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_satisfacao_sat_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="satisfacao"
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_sat_email" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Deixe seu Comentário:"
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_Mensagem_sat_email"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#d8d6d3"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="Comente aqui"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="6"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Qual o problema com o seu código?

Comment: Ele não está validando o `EditText` quando clico no Enviar do `AlertDialog`.

Comment: txtMensagemSatEmail é um TextView ta querendo validar um TextView? Ta validando algo baseado num TextView ?

Comment: Ele é um `EditText`, foi apenas a nome da variável.

Comment: Não bastaria por um `return` no fim do código dentro do `if`?

Comment: Coloquei, apenas fechou o `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Se quer manter o dialog aberto no caso dos dados introduzidos não serem válidos veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63039/2541).

Comment: Não consegui, no 2º passo, eu travo, na parte de declarar o `button`, não existe `setButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, para tratar um evento de click do botão no alertdialog, sem que ele feche, chame o `método setOnShowListener (new DialogInterface.OnShowLister);`
Nesse método você recupera o botão positive para tratar o evento no click dentro do método onShow(), segue o exemplo para o seu código:

```
View vView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.envio_satisfacao_ruim, null);
        edtMensagemSatEmail = (EditText) vView.findViewById(R.id.edt_Mensagem_sat_email);
        edtMensagemSatEmail.setFocusable(true);



AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Seu Titulo")
            .setView( vView)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Enviar", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    final AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
    //Aqui você trata o click do button positive sem que o alertdialog feche em caso de convergência
    mDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button postive = mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            postive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //aqui você trata o evento
                    if (edtMensagemSatEmail.getText().length() == 0) {
                        edtMensagemSatEmail.setError("Campo obrigatório");
                        edtMensagemSatEmail.setFocusable(true);
                        edtMensagemSatEmail.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        //Como ao clicar no botão positivo a condição é verificada
                        //caso esteja tudo certo com o edittext, então chama o seu método
                        //enviar email
                        enviarEmail();
                        //No final como já completou a condição pode dar dismiss
                        //no alertdialog, pois está tudo ok
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
    mDialog.show();
```

Obs: Eu não testei, mas tenho certeza que está funcionando pra sua necessidade. Funcionando ou não, dá um feedback. Abraço

Comment: olá, ele rodou, mas ainda continua fechando o alerta se não informar nada no `EditText`, editei e postei o meu atualizado pelo seu.

Comment: Mesmo informando no `EditText` Está fechando o `Dialog` sem fazer a ação

Comment: @AriMelo testei e tá funcionando sim, siga fielmente a minha resposta que dará certo. Pelo código que você editou no final do alertdialog vc tá chamando:

`caixaDialog.setView(vView);
            AlertDialog dialog = caixaDialog.create();
            dialog.show();`

Ou seja, está recriando o alerta sem os métodos de onShow.  Então remova essa parte e coloque apenas: `mDialog.show();`

Comment: Só me corrigindo, ali no final do alertdialog pelo seu código, você está criando uma outra view pro dialog, e não criando um novo alerta. Isso anula os métodos que está fazendo o tratamento do evento de click.

Comment: Não funcionou, quando abre o `Dialog`, mostra apenas os botões cancelar e enviar mais nada, como se o corpo sumisse, editei novamente do jeito que está o projeto.

Comment: tem como colocar o xml do seu alerta? Pelo código deveria estar funcionando. Testei esse meu em uma api 28 e tá ok. Única diferença no seu código é no método do botão Cancel, coloque o dialog.cancel, no final do método, pois do jeito que está os métodos abaixo não é executado. E no envento de click do botão positivo ao invés de mDialog.dismiss(); é dialog.dismiss()

Comment: Postado no Início.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94075/discussion-between-murillo-comino-and-ari-melo).

Comment: Ao invés de usar os botões do próprio `AlertDialog`, criei 2 botões no layout, e funcionou a validação, vlw.

Comment: Que bom brother, mas estranho desse jeito com os botões do alertdialog não ir.

Answer (score 0):

Na criacao da instancia voce esta colocando ***edtMensagemSatEmail = (TextView)*** e nao ***edtMensagemSatEmail = (EditText )***

e coloca o else

```
if (edtMensagemSatEmail.getText().length() == 0) {
                        edtMensagemSatEmail.setError("Campo obrigatório");
                        edtMensagemSatEmail.setFocusable(true);
                        edtMensagemSatEmail.requestFocus();
                    }
else
    enviarEmail();
```

provavelmente ele valida sim, mas logo em seguida vai para o método enviarEmail(); e la nele você deve ter colocado alguma rotina para fechar, se colocar no else ele só vai para o enviarEmail() se passar na validação.

Comment: mesmo com `EditText` não está validando, quando clico em enviar passa direto.

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: acho que faltava o else, testa de novo

Comment: Certo, ele não envia. Só que ele fecha o `AlertDialog`, queria que ele ficasse com o `Dialog` aberto e setasse no campo `edtMensagemSatEmail.setError("Campo obrigatório");`